# I cannot work "in" my part job anymore due to my back problem

Tags: grammar

I want to write the next sentence, but I don't know what preposition I should use.

I cannot work "in" my part job anymore due to my back problem.

Comment: A stylistic note: using both "work" and "job" in the same sentence is redundant and therefore a bit unnatural sounding (also, it should be "part-time job", not "part job"). I'd say "I cannot do my part-time job..." or "I cannot go to my part-time job..." or "I cannot work part-time..."

Comment: [More often,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=work+in+my+job%2Cwork+at+my+job%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwork%20in%20my%20job%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwork%20at%20my%20job%3B%2Cc0) it's *...work **at** my job*.